# Setup NewRelic in java application hosted in azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, newrelic

I have written an application(Web) using java. I have hosted it in azure app service.
Configuration of App service is

> OS : Linux
> WebServer : Tomcat 8.5 and Java 8

For configuring newrelic i have downloaded agent and uploaded it in home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT folder of azure app service.

One more step i need to perform is to add following command in catalina.bat

`set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -javaagent home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/newrelic/newrelic.jar`

When i am trying to update catalina.bat which i found inside /usr/local/tomcat/bin and restarts the app service, my changes are getting reverted back.

Any other way by which i can able to configure newrelic for my application?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibility:

1. Guided install: https://docs.newrelic.com/whats-new/2021/04/java-net/
2. Try to add / before the path (home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/newrelic/newrelic.jar --> /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/newrelic/newrelic.jar)